# How to prevent the background from zooming?

Tags: background-image, zooming

I have made a webpage with a background:

```
<style>
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mouse+Memoirs);

    body {
        background-image: url('Header.png');
        margin: 0;
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Mouse Memoirs', sans-serif;
    }
</style>

<div align="center">
    <h2>ThePeopleHubProject</h2>
</div>
```

How can I prevent the background from distorting when zooming?

I don't want it to be able to do this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lcd7O.jpg

Only this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu4O3.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
html { 
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

That should get you pretty far...